# Complete future if certain condition happens

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future, rust-tokio

I would like to create a future that completes if a certain value is received over a UDP connection.

To clarify, assume I send a ping with id 2 and want to asynchronously wait for the pong with the same id. My idea was to use something like `send_ping(endpoint, id) -> Future` and work with the future (e.g. passing it to other functions) knowing that it either resolves to the matching pong or to a timeout.

A sketch of my idea:

```
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate futures;

use tokio_core::reactor::*;
use futures::Stream;
use futures::sync::mpsc;

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();

    // simulate my UDP socket connection
    let (remote, socket) = mpsc::unbounded::<i32>();
    remote.unbounded_send(1).unwrap();
    remote.unbounded_send(2).unwrap();
    remote.unbounded_send(3).unwrap();

    let reader = socket.for_each(|id| {
        println!("received {}", id);
        Ok(())
    });

    // create future which completes if 2 is received
    // or after a given timeout

    core.run(reader).unwrap();
}
```

Is this even possible? I cannot find any examples.

Comment: Your question is not very clear; why are you using `for_each`? What do you want to happen when the socket/channel is empty?

Comment: I want to listen to the socket forever. Therefore the `for_each`.

Comment: You could write your own `Future` (which could, on finding a matching item/packet, also return the inner stream, so you can continue using it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tokio_timer::Timer::timeout_stream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-timer/0.1.2/tokio_timer/struct.Timer.html#method.timeout_stream) and [`futures::Stream::filter`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.filter):

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tokio_timer;

use tokio_core::reactor::*;
use futures::Stream;
use futures::sync::mpsc;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let timer = tokio_timer::Timer::default();

    // simulate my UDP socket connection
    let (remote, socket) = mpsc::unbounded::<i32>();
    remote.unbounded_send(1).unwrap();
    remote.unbounded_send(2).unwrap();
    remote.unbounded_send(3).unwrap();

    let consumer = timer
        .timeout_stream(socket, Duration::from_secs(2))
        .filter(|&v| v == 2)
        .for_each(|id| {
            println!("received {}", id);
            Ok(())
        });

    println!("{:?}", core.run(consumer));
}
```

Comment: How does this complete on the first matching item?  Afaict this only completes after the timout or end-of-stream.  You could return an error from `for_each` to abort the loop, but then you don't need a separate `filter` call - this can be done directly from `for_each`.

Comment: @Stefan I admit that I'm partially trying to guess and fill in missing pieces as to what the OP wants. They state that they "want to listen to the socket forever", but they also seem to end the program. I took that to actually mean "I want to do something for every matching response, with a timeout on each step". If you think I guessed wrong, that's totally plausible! I'd encourage you to ask clarification or provide your own answer if that's the case, as well.